# I want to open IE browser and then Chrome Browser from a same program

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

```
require 'watir'
b1=Watir::Browser.new 
b=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b1.goto "www.google.com"
b.goto 'www.yahoo.com'
```

I am writing the above code to open google.com in IE and yahoo.com in Chrome but both are opening in IE, May I know how to accomplish this task?

Comment: What does just doing `Watir::Browser.new :chrome` do? Do you have chromedriver installed?

Comment: Yes, We have installed because `Watir::Browser.new :chrome` statement alone opens Chrome browser. Only when I combine as I have given, both are opening in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use `require 'watir-webdriver'` because the default behavior when using `require 'watir'` right now is using a deprecated approach with IE. (We'll be fixing this soon).

Also, please specify each instead of relying on the default.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b1 = Watir::Browser.new :ie
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b1.goto 'www.google.com'
b.goto 'www.yahoo.com'
```

Comment: `b1 = Watir::Browser.new :ie` opens the IE browser using Watir-webdriver but I have to open the IE browser using Watir-classic.

Comment: Watir-classic is deprecated, you should try to get your tests passing in watir-webdriver. Switching between watir classic and watir-webdriver in the same session is likely what is causing your issue.

Comment: I can't use watir-weddriver because `Watir::Browser.attach(:index,0)` statement doesn't work.

Comment: Attach won't work for Chrome or Firefox, either. Just start the browser in irb, then you can do whatever you want with it manually and still interact with the browser via Watir on the command line.